# toByteArray in Python?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("1000");
Byte[] arr = i.toByteArray();
Contents of arr: [3, -24]
```

Since byte range in java is: minimum -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

The `java.math.BigInteger.toByteArray()` returns a byte array containing the two's-complement representation of this BigInteger. The byte array will be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.

How can I do this in python 2.7?
Since the byte range there is 0 <= byte <= 255
e.g.

```
x = 1000
list = doTheMagic(x)
```

and as a result I get:

```
list = [3, -24]
```

Comment: I guess you don't want to do multiple divisions by 256?

Comment: I am new to python... I need anything that will provide me the same functionality as the java`s toByteArray.

Comment: By the way, Python doesn't have a "byte" type. It has integer, which has varying size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) and [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

```
>>> struct.unpack('2b', struct.pack('>h', 1000))
(3, -24)
>>> struct.unpack('4b', struct.pack('>I', 1000))
(0, 0, 3, -24)
>>> struct.unpack('8b', struct.pack('>Q', 1000))
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, -24)
```

Unfortunately, you can't get abitrary length byte array using `struct.pack`/`struct.unpack`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want, something like that could do the trick.

```
def doTheMagic(x):
    l = []
    while x:
        m = x%256
        l.append(m if m <=127 else m-256)
        x /= 256
    return l[::-1]

x = 1000
l = doTheMagic(x)

print l
```

Answer (score 0):

[user189's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23871809/10840) is almost correct. Sometimes [`BigInteger.toByteArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray()) adds an extra zero byte to its result. Here's a more correct solution:

```
def to_byte_array(num):
    bytea = []
    n = num
    while n:
        bytea.append(n % 256)
        n //= 256
    n_bytes = len(bytea)
    if 2 ** (n_bytes * 8 - 1) <= num < 2 ** (n_bytes * 8):
        bytea.append(0)
    return bytearray(reversed(bytea))
```